# Does Linux kernel scheduler care about how many socket/core/threads?

Tags: linux, kernel, performance, kvm

I am running openstack + kvm and default when I build VM on openstack CPU Topology is number of vCPU = sockets

Example:

If I create VM with 32vCPU then my `lscpu` looks like following.

```
# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             16
```

Its saying my guest VM has 16 socket and each socket has 1 core with 2 threads, yes in real-world this not nearly impossible to have 16 socket on motherboard so question is does linux kernel make scheduling decision based on CPU Topology?

Just trying to understand what best CPU Topology would be good for guest performance

more socket vs more core ?

## EDIT

I am following all best practices for openstack performance like CPU Pinning, reserve pCPU for host, HugePage, SRIOV etc.

Comment: Does [this post](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/cloud-computing/2014/10/16/openstack-guest-cpu-topology-configuration-part-one/) and [this post](https://messeiry.com/cpu-pinning-in-openstack/) help? It looks like you can perform CPU pinning to get the best performance but what would be the best performance depends on your underlying hardware.

Comment: I do have CPU pinning already configure with hugePage (I did follow all best practices to tune openstack and KVM)

Comment: In those posts they discuss using the property `hw:cpu_sockets=NN` to limit the number of sockets exposed. The default is to have the sockets match the number of vCPU's you expose to the guest. Do you have more than 1 socket? Are you noticing your VM having performance issues that it should not have? You say you are using best practices for openstack performance so is the performance matching your expectations of the hardware?

Comment: My all other application working fine except `erlang`, erlang doing poor job on VM vs bare metal, I have created single big VM on compute node with 32vCPU and performance is bad.. when i tell erlang to bind all CPU to numa0 then performance is good so trying to understand why erlang with dual numa on VM not performing well (it felt like erlang does care about CPUTopology to schedule its job and as you seen in my output KVM not providing true CPU Topology, I have tried to match VM socket/core/threads with Host but still performance is bad

Comment: @kemotep, and the application mix running on the machine.

Comment: @Satish, it seems your problem is with Erlang (or the programs writren in it you run)...

Answer (score 2):

No, Linux does not care about Sockets. Check out the [Kernel.org documentation on CPU Topology](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/topology.txt). This relevant passage should shed light on the situation.

> The kernel does not care about the concept of physical sockets because a
>   socket has no relevance to software. It's an electromechanical component. In
>   the past a socket always contained a single package (see below), but with the
>   advent of Multi Chip Modules (MCM) a socket can hold more than one package.

Openstack's defaults of making the number of sockets be equal to the number of vCPU's. From the [OpenStack Wiki](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/VirtDriverGuestCPUTopology) comes this passage (emphasis mine):

> **Each virtualization driver in OpenStack has its own approach to defining the CPU topology seen by guest virtual machines. The libvirt driver will expose all vCPUs as individual sockets, with 1 core and no hyper-threads.**
>
> UNIX operating systems will happily use any CPU topology that is exposed to them within a upper bound on the total number of logical CPUs. That said there can be performance implications from choosing different topologies. For example, 2 hyper-threads are usually not equivalent in performance to 2 cores or sockets, and as such operating system schedulers have special logic to deal with task placement. So if a host has a CPU with 2 cores with 2 threads, and two tasks to run, it will try to place them on different cores, rather than in different threads within a core. It follows that if a guest is shown 4 sockets, **the operating system will not be making optimal scheduler placement decisions to avoid competing for constrained thread resources**.

So we have conflicting information from the Linux kernel documentation and Openstack documentation. The Linux kernel docs say that sockets are a meaningless term in the grand scheme of things now that we have multi-chip modules. However, it appears that Openstack points out that the UNIX scheduler will prefer "physical cores" over "logical cores" for tasks and run into constraints treating each core as its own socket. However, this fails to account for the scalable nature of Openstack or of VM's. If Openstack is running across a cluster of servers, would limiting the cores to 1 socket make sense?

So is it important to *you* that your virtual topology of you VM matches that of your physical Topology? Is your physical topology ever going to be "the cloud" or otherwise in a cluster of many servers?

Comment: Linus *does* care about CPU threads, as they share cache with their neighbors, and that is performance critical. But simulated CPUs don't behave like physical ones...

Comment: @vonbrand I would agree that *Linus* cares but the kernel scheduler appears to be robust enough that you can abstract the hardware away and still achieve decent performance. A hyper-converged high availability cluster of VM's are going to have no clue about what the cores are and where they are which is great because you can span this architecture across the globe and run "the cloud" off of it. User Satish seems to be losing performance with their erlang program when it is run on a VM compared to bare metal which is a different sort of question then the one he asking about the scheduler.

Comment: exactly what I commented. Their Erlang *programs* have bad performance, they tweak machine configurations...